# Fetch data based on key

Tags: json, perl, unix, key

```
{ "Labels": [ {"Test": 99.25341796875, "Name": "Skateboard" }, { "Test": 9.25341796875, "Name": "Sport" }, { "Test": 49.24723052978516, "Name": "People" }]}
```

I need to remove the Testtag on basis of below conditions
if Test value >50 then replace Test=Major 
if Test value <50 then replace with Test=Minor

so here output requested is like below.

```
{ "Labels": [ {"High": 99.25341796875, "Name": "Skateboard" }, { "Low": 9.25341796875, "Name": "Sport" }, { "Low": 49.24723052978516, "Name": "People" }]}
```

Comment: are you serializing this content into objects at all? like in Java or C#?

Comment: Thanks Alex for formatting. I need it in Perl/Unix.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
$json = '{ "Labels": [ {"Confidence": 99.25341796875, "Name": "Skateboard" }, { "Confidence": 9.25341796875, "Name": "Sport" }, { "Confidence": 49.24723052978516, "Name": "People" }]}';


$text = decode_json($json);
print  Dumper $text;

$key = "Confidence";
if (exists($text{$key}))
{
  print "Found Confidence\n";
  #sed i need to apply using chekcing condition of Confidence < 50 or >50 and replace tag with monor and major
}
else
{
  print "Could not find Confidence";
}


This is what i did so far. Pl suggest

Comment: Please update your code in question so that it is easy to read

Answer (score 1):

[***jq***](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) solution:

```
jq '.Labels |= map(.[(if .Confidence > 50 then "High" else "Low" end)]= .Confidence | del(.Confidence))' yourfile.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "Labels": [
    {
      "Name": "Skateboard",
      "High": 99.25341796875
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sport",
      "Low": 9.25341796875
    },
    {
      "Name": "People",
      "Low": 49.24723052978516
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @PraveenPokharia, I'm not Alex

Comment: I am not able to redirect the output of above command to a file. Please suggest. It is displaying on the screen.

Comment: i tried it but it is not working..                                                                        
jq '.Labels |= map(.[(if .Confidence > 50 then "High" else "Low" end)]= .Confidence | del(.Confidence))' $filename.json > $filename1.json

Comment: it is making a file but the content has not changed which we changed with the jq :). pl suggest so that same output which is coming above from ur query preserve in the file.

Comment: I got the output but it is in 1 file. i have applied for loop to iterate the 10 files and redirected the json o/p of 10 files in 1 file due to which it looks clumsy.